# Package Version Conflict

Tags: python, python-requests, streamlit, requirements.txt, pyrebase

I tried to install all the packages in the requirements.txt file of a python app inside a venv, but two different packages require 2 different versions of request library. How can i resolve this.

ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 53), pyrebase==3.0.27 and requests==2.31.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:

1. The user requested requests==2.31.0
2. navigation 0.1 depends on requests
3. pyrebase 3.0.27 depends on requests==2.11.1

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

Comment: The conflict is due to a package that hasn't been updated in 7 years specifying (likely) too-strict requirements. #1 is the only real option; I would start by looking at https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/requirements.txt, installing the latest versions of the dependencies, then testing if the code works. If you're lucky, all the `==` should have been `>=` in the first place; otherwise you'll have to experiment with older versions of the dependencies until you find a combination that works.